# load_missing_constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, docker

System details:
-Linux
-Docker version 17.03.0-ce
-Ruby version 1.8.7
-Rails version 2.3.8.

In the process of dockerizing a Ruby on Rails app, I'm faced with the following error on running script/server i.e. starting the rails' built-in web server:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in **`load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Api::InjectTokenIntoCookies (NameError)**

This particular file (InjectTokenIntoCookies) is present in a separate Plugins folder. The farthest I've gotten with resolving this issue is that it's a case of missing gems. However, setting up the entire rails environment in a docker container just adds to the complexity.

"RUN bundle install" is included in the Dockerfile so that shouldn't be an issue.

Full error trace:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Api::InjectTokenIntoCookies (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    from /bab/apps/site/config/initializers/api_middleware.rb:1
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /bab/apps/site/config/environment.rb:6
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /bab/apps/site/script/server:3:in `gem_original_require'
    from /bab/apps/site/script/server:3:in `require'
    from /bab/apps/site/script/server:3
```

Comment: Add all related things, the script  you're launching the full error trace and so on.

Comment: Just so you know, ruby 1.8.7 reached EOL on July 31, 2014.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _“is there life after death”_ and other burning questions in today’s newscast.